# Error starting jHipster Microservices with consul

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, jhipster, consul

I'm trying to build sample microservice app using this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdcnpD-GpZ4&t=793s&list=FLPklPmIqxhF_4tpb9YmTC_A&index=1).
Jhipster version is 4.0.6
So i've created gateway, service and started consul using this command:

```
docker-compose -f src/main/docker/consul.yml up
```

from my gateway directory.
But the error occur on Spring Boot startup, here is the log:

```
2017-02-22 11:52:25.679 ERROR 3168 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.c.c.ConsulPropertySourceLocator    : Fail fast is set and there was an error reading configuration from consul.

2017-02-22 11:52:32.491  WARN 3168 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2a5b2096: startup date [Thu Jan 01 03:00:00 AST 1970]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5108df79)
com.ecwid.consul.transport.TransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Could you please assist with this issue?

UPDATE:
I've found that app tries to make GET request to URL on staptup:

```
http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/config/armory,dev/?recurse&token=
```

But the only data stored in Consul K/V storage is:

```
KEY: config/application/data

VALUE:
configserver:
    name: Docker Consul Service
    status: Connected to Consul Server running in Docker

jhipster:
    security:
        authentication:
            jwt:
                secret: my-secret-token-to-change-in-production
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must copy your application yaml configurations into your consul instance [as explained in the doc](https://jhipster.github.io/microservices-architecture/#consul) into `central-server-config` directory if consul is running in dev profile or in its git repo if consul is running in prod profile.

So assuming your app is named "armory" you should copy your `src/main/resources/config/application.yml` to `armory.yml` and for each profiles (e.g. `application-dev.yml` to `armory-dev.yml`)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please also assist with overriding default consul port from 'localhost' to docker's one? Where should i change it?

Comment: I don't know, have you looked in bootstrap.yml of your app?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, @Tolledo did you find a solution?

Comment: @Martin, yes. Just reinstall docker using DockerToolbox and the issue should be gone.